# Incremental conditions to filter elements of given collection

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-8, java-stream

I would like to know an scalable and generic way to apply incremental `filters` to a given collection, without losing the cause of the failure, I mean, which filter does not match.

The following code is a simplification of the existing one (it has more conditions and error messages):

```
public class FailureCause {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateAtRawWay(asList(201, 300, 450));
    validateAtRawWay(asList(20, 30, 40));
    validateAtRawWay(asList(400, 1600));
    validateAtRawWay(asList(10, 25, 36, 201, 1600));
  }

  public static void validateAtRawWay(List<Integer> sourceToCheck) {
    System.out.println("Initial elements: " + sourceToCheck);

    if (!sourceToCheck.stream()
            .filter(FailureCause.upTo100())
            .findAny()
            .isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: no numbers less or equals than 100 were found");
        return;
    }
    if (!sourceToCheck.stream()
            .filter(FailureCause.isPerfectSquare())
            .findAny()
            .isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: no perfect square numbers were found");
        return;
    }
    List<Integer> validResults = sourceToCheck.stream()
            .filter(FailureCause.upTo100())
            .filter(FailureCause.isPerfectSquare())
            .collect(toList());
    System.out.println("Valid data: " + validResults);
  }

  public static Predicate<Integer> upTo100() {
    return i -> i <= 100;
  }

  public static Predicate<Integer> isPerfectSquare() {
    return i -> {
        double sq = Math.sqrt(i);
        return (sq - Math.floor(sq)) == 0;
    };
  }
}
```

However, with that approach the collection has to be iterated several times to know the error and finally, get the suitable elements that verify all conditions.

**As alternative to the above approach** I have developed the following class to store:  the filters, its importance order, error message and if there was an element that verified it.

```
public class ConditionToMatch<E> implements Comparable<ConditionToMatch> {

  // To omit getter/setter
  public int order;
  public Predicate<E> condition;
  public boolean wasFound;
  public String errorMessage;

  public ConditionToMatch (int order, Predicate<E> condition, boolean wasFound, String errorMessage) {
    this.order = order;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.wasFound = wasFound;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ConditionToMatch o) {
    return ofNullable(o)
            .map(ext -> Integer.compare(order, ext.order))
            .orElse(-1);
  }
}
```

Adding this use case, to the previous `FailureCause` class:

```
public class FailureCause {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    validateWithConditionClass(asList(201, 300, 450));
    validateWithConditionClass(asList(20, 30, 40));
    validateWithConditionClass(asList(400, 1600));
    validateWithConditionClass(asList(10, 25, 36, 201, 1600));
  }
  ...

  public static void validateWithConditionClass(List<Integer> sourceToCheck) {
    System.out.println("Initial elements: " + sourceToCheck);

    ConditionToMatch<Integer> isUpTo100Condition = isUpTo100ConditionToMatch();
    ConditionToMatch<Integer> isPerfectSquareCondition = isPerfectSquareConditionToMatch();

    // Used to get the "most important" filter has failed
    PriorityQueue<ConditionToMatch> priorizeValidations = new PriorityQueue<>(asList(isUpTo100Condition, isPerfectSquareCondition));

    List<Integer> validResults = sourceToCheck.stream()
            .map(s -> {
                if (isUpTo100Condition.condition.test(s)) {
                    isUpTo100Condition.wasFound = true;
                }
                if (isPerfectSquareCondition.condition.test(s)) {
                    isPerfectSquareCondition.wasFound = true;
                }
                return s;
            })
            .filter(isUpTo100Condition.condition)
            .filter(isPerfectSquareCondition.condition)
            .collect(toList());

    if (validResults.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<ConditionToMatch> value = priorizeValidations.iterator();
        // To know the first "most important" filter that failed
        while (value.hasNext()) {
            ConditionToMatch current = value.next();
            if (!current.wasFound) {
                System.out.println(current.errorMessage);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Valid data: " + validResults);
    }
  }
  ...  

  public static ConditionToMatch<Integer> isUpTo100ConditionToMatch() {
    return new ConditionToMatch<>(1, FailureCause.upTo100(), false, "ERROR: no numbers less or equals than 100 were found");
  }

  public static ConditionToMatch<Integer> isPerfectSquareConditionToMatch() {
    return new ConditionToMatch<>(2, FailureCause.isPerfectSquare(), false, "ERROR: no perfect square numbers were found");
  }
}
```

My question is: *is there a better and scalable way to do it?*

Comment: why not use `peek` with tagged logs?

Comment: You should use `peek` instead of map since you do not modify the stream items, like @Naman suggested.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, but it is only a "proof of concept", asking for a better approach to solve it

Comment: @doctore can you define a better approach? the code for example that you've shared uses `map` at the line (`.map(s -> {
                if (isUpTo100Condition.condition.test(s)) {
                    isUpTo100Condition.wasFound = true;
                }
                if (isPerfectSquareCondition.condition.test(s)) {
                    isPerfectSquareCondition.wasFound = true;
                }
                return s;
            })`) to perform something very similar to what `peek` could be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adapt your first approach and avoid streams there.

```
import static java.util.function.Predicate.not;
...

public static void validateAtRawWay(List<Integer> sourceToCheck) {
    List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(sourceToCheck);
    System.out.println("Initial elements: " + copy);
    
    copy.removeIf(not(upTo100()));
    if (copy.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: no numbers less or equals than 100 were found");
        return;
    }
    
    copy.removeIf(not(isPerfectSquare()));
    if (copy.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: no perfect square numbers were found");
        return;
    }
    
    List<Integer> validResults = copy;
    System.out.println("Valid data: " + validResults);
}
```

I don't know how many conditions you have to check. Even if you have to repeat yourself often with this example, i think it is more legible. You could also extract a method that accepts a list and a predicate to reduce the repeated blocks.

Comment: Good alternative. Not sure if `removeIf` has a better performance than `filter`

Comment: filter does not loop? removeIf does like map but the cost of iterating is usually small.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more easily by setting the boolean value directly in ConditionToMatch class:

```
public class ConditionToMatch<E> implements Predicate<E> {
  public Predicate<E> condition;
  public boolean neverMatchedAnything = true;
  public String errorMessage;

  public ConditionToMatch (Predicate<E> condition, int order, String errorMessage) {
    this.order = order;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test(E e) {
     boolean value = condition.test(e)
    if (value) {
      neverMatchedAnything = false;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then you can write a generic checker:

```
public static void validateWithConditionClass(List<Integer> sourceToCheck, List<ConditionToMatch<Integer>> conditions) {
    System.out.println("Initial elements: " + sourceToCheck);
    conditions.sort((c1, c2) -> c2.order - c1.order);

    Stream<Integer> stream sourceToCheck.stream();
    for (ConditionToMatch<Integer> condition : conditions) 
      stream = stream.filter(condition)
    }
    List<Integer> results = streams.collect();

    for (ConditionToMatch<Integer> condition : conditions) 
      if (condition.neverMatchedAnything) {
        System.out.println(current.errorMessage);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

And the specific implementation for your 2 checkers:

```
public static void validateWithConditionClass(List<Integer> sourceToCheck) {
    List<ConditionToMatch<Integer>> conditions = Arrays.toList({isUpTo100ConditionToMatch(), isPerfectSquareConditionToMatch()});
    validateWithConditionClass(sourceToCheck, conditions);
  }
```

And of course the functions to create the conditions:

```
  public static ConditionToMatch<Integer> isUpTo100ConditionToMatch() {
return new ConditionToMatch<>(FailureCause.upTo100(), 1, "ERROR: no numbers less or equals than 100 were found");
  }

  public static ConditionToMatch<Integer> isPerfectSquareConditionToMatch() {
return new ConditionToMatch<>( FailureCause.isPerfectSquare(), 2, "ERROR: no perfect square numbers were found");
  }
```

Comment: +1 due to is a simpler code than mine using the same approach. However, I prefer avoid something like `conditions.sort((c1, c2) -> c2.index - c1.index);` because in that way it is required to be careful with how the conditions were included in the list, instead of defining the "priority" in the `ConditionToMatch` itself.

Comment: Why so ? We sort according to priority (order)? I agree I made a typo, I change index to order

Comment: Yes, maybe the name of the property `order` in my example is not the most suitable one. I used it to "set the priority"

Comment: My implementations has several avantages: no map (1 less loop) and if one of filter remove the elements, it will not set the wasFound for the second condition. It also scale to any number of condition without changing the code.

Comment: Yes, your code has several improvements (although there are some "missing parts" easy to include). However to get the same results and order verifying the conditions, it is required to change how the ordination is done: `conditions.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(c -> c.order));`